# K and R exercise 1-22

Tags: c

I am doing programs in The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie.

I am currently at exercise 1-22 that says:

> Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after the `last > non-blank character` that occurs before the n-th column of input.
>   Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long line, and if there are  > no blanks or tabs before the specified column.

My problem is not how to do the program...
My problem is where am I supposed to fold the line.

What does that "after the last non-blank character" means? Where should I fold the line?

Please guys DON'T tell me the program itself. I want to do it on my own.

I just want to know the point where I am supposed to fold the line.

**EDIT**: There is another problem...

What if my line contains `tabs`? In that case column length of the line increases from the character length. Which length should be considered?

**EDIT 2**:

Something intelligent...
To tackle the case of tabs, I have an idea...

There are 2 exercise before 1-22 -- 1-20 and 1-21. Which are entab and detab... you guys must be knowing... So I will first detab the line then fold it and then entab the folded lines... I think that's gonna be the most intelligent in case of tabs. Any one?

Comment: "Please guys DON'T tell me the program itself. I want to do it on my own." - That itself is worth an upvote.

Comment: Blank characters are all forms of spaces. It is basically asking you to not split words in two.

Comment: Try folding the line after the last non-blank character before the 80th column

Comment: Just that this `Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long line` is quite ambiguous... Is it telling the reader to break the word?

Comment: I don't think you should treat tabs any differently to spaces at this point.  If you really wanted to, you could treat a tab as being equal to say, four characters, which would make your program slightly more complex.

Comment: You're asking good questions. There are many possible designs, and the specification allows many of them to be correct. If you don't want to deal with tabs specially, there is no need to do so. If you want to deal with tabs, you'll have to decide how the 'tab stops' are set — is it every 8th position, or 4th, or some other value (8 is the classic; programs like `pr` use `-e 4` to set width 4). But that in turn presupposes that you can handle command line arguments. If you're learning C _and_ learning to program, that is too complex; if you're already a programmer, maybe it's doable.

Comment: Exactly: This is why I mention in my answer below that it's up to you to decide what to do if the exercise is a little vague.  You'll be learning whatever you decide to do, so do as much or as little as you feel confident doing.

Comment: Something intelligent...
To tackle the case of tabs, I have an idea...
There are 2 exercise before 1-22 -- 1-20 and 1-21. Which are entab and detab... you guys must be knowing...
So
I will first detab the line then fold it and then entab the folded lines... I think that's gonna be the most intelligent in case of tabs.
Any one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this exercise is basically emulating a "word-wrap" function you might see on a text editor.  "blank" would mean "whitespace", e.g. space or tab characters.

Example:

```
"Once upon a time"
```

If you were asked to "fold" that line after the 14th column of input, the 14th character is the "i" in "time".  Your output should be two lines: `"Once upon a", "time"`.

The question also says to be intelligent with very long lines.

For example,

```
"Once upon a time Once upon a time Once upon a time"
```

If you were splitting this line at 14 characters, you should consider the fact that the line must be split into more than two lines.

There is also the case when a word could be very long, preventing you from splitting it:

```
"Deoxyribonucleicacid is DNA"
```

If you split that at 14 characters, you would not find any whitespace characters until `" is"`, so the word should be split.

Finally, I'd agree that the question is slightly ambiguous, but as long as you're writing code somewhat along the lines of what is required, you're learning, so I wouldn't worry about getting too hung-up on the details.  Good luck :)

Comment: That is where I am confused...
Since Non-blank means anything except ' ', '\t' and '\n'.

Comment: Yes, so you fold at the last character "back" from the nth column that is not blank. Meaning you work your way back until you find a whitespace from the position you want to break at - the break at the one just ahead of the space.

Comment: @MatsPetersson perfect! agreed!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example: let's say `n = 6` (for the simplicity of counting) and the line that you need to fold looks like this:

```
Got all chars on one line.
00000000001111111111222222
01234567890123456789012345
```

Go through the characters counting the current position in the line that you are producing. When you see a whitespace, go back to find the last non-space char *before* it, and makr its position. When your counter reaches `n`, see where was the last non-blank character preceding a space in the original line, and fold the line.

In the example above, the first space that you see is at the position 3. At this point you go back one char, mark 2 as the last non-blank preceding the space, and go on. When the count reaches 6 (at character `'l'`), split the line at position 3, and reset the current position back to zero. Continue with the algorithm to fold at 7, 13, and 20.

```
Got
all
chars
on one
line
```